# Populating new DB table from other table data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi there basically i have 2 tables with 162 entries and im trying to populate a new table with entries from the other tables to show the difference between a number value

```
  Insert Into popdiff(
  popdiff)
  select (a.malepop+a.femalepop)-(b.malepop+b.femalepop)     
  from tablea a, tableb b;
```

The problem im having is it is returning 26244 results i.e. 162*162 rather than 162 which im expecting, having looked into it a bit the query is finding the value for each entry in tablea- the 162 values in tableb

how can i simply return just the 162 rows?

Comment: use `from a join b on a.id=b.id`

Comment: Without a join specified to associate the rows between the two tables, you get a Cartesian join which links each row in one table with each row in the other.

Comment: got it working using this suggestion thanks vp_arth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the relationship between the two tables and that's a cross join which returns what you described. Specify the relationship either in a `WHERE` condition or a `JOIN` condition.

WHERE:

```
SELECT (a.malepop+a.femalepop)-(b.malepop+b.femalepop)     
FROM tablea a, tableb b;
WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

JOIN:

```
SELECT (a.malepop+a.femalepop)-(b.malepop+b.femalepop)     
FROM tablea a
INNER JOIN tableb b ON a.id = b.id;
```

Of course, you may have different names for the IDs, so change the `a.id = b.id` consition accordingly.

Comment: thanks i got it working using vp_arths suggestion in the comments but thanks for helping with the understanding of what this is doing!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do an inner join:
select (a.malepop+a.femalepop)-(b.malepop+b.femalepop)
  from tableA join tableB using (field)

That will do the job